# QProcessEnvironment a value with spaces and quotes

Tags: c++, qt, escaping, environment-variables, qprocess

I am setting the environment for a program I will be launching using QProcess.  One of the environment variables I need to set MAY contain spaces, slashes, and quotes.  What is the right way to handle this?

I've tried escaping quotes, and adding a \" to either end of the string but my environment variable is always blank.  Can someone share a code sample of how to handle this?

I'm thinking about this:

```
a = "\""+a.replace(QRegExp(QLatin1String("(\\\\*)\"")), QLatin1String("\\1\\1\\\""))+"\"";
```

but after numerous attempts I thought I would ask for help too.

For example, if a is:

```
A" \ / '
```

and I try to set an environment variable through

```
environment << "a=\""+a+"\""
```

and pass environment as the first parameters for a qprocess run, then the variable is NOT set when the qprocess starts, due to the fact that the environment ignores the malformed string.

Comment: Try to set an environment variable to [X" c' ] in your QProcessEnvironment then run a shell, and you will see the variable is NOT set.  It has to be escaped.  That is my question...how to escape it properly

Comment: Such things are very much platform dependent. What is the exact platform? (Windows version or Linux distribution, and exact Qt version and bitness). What you describe may be a bug or a platform limitation.

Comment: Running Qt 5.1.0 on RedHat 6, 64 bit.

Comment: `QProcessEnvironment` doesn't have an `operator<<`. It has an `insert` method. Your code doesn't agree with your narrative: in the title you claim use of `QProcessEnvironment`, yet the code looks like you use the old `setEnvironment` call that takes a string list. You should *not* be using the old `setEnvironment` method. Use `setProcessEnvironment` method instead.

Comment: I build a QStringList of environment variables and then insert them one at a time into the QProcessEnvrionment.  I didn't say QProcessEnvironment has an operator<<.

Comment: What I'm saying is: don't do it the way you do! Use the `QProcessEnvironment` class and the `setProcessEnvironmentCall`.

Comment: I build a string list, and then add them one at a time to QProcessEnvironment.  The first parameter of QProcess run is a QProcessEnvironment.  But his is getting more off topic - please leave comments relating to the top